# Sufficiency of studying the convergence of the sequence of reals $(F(x+\frac{1}{n}))$ for studying the right continuity of cdf $F$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, continuity, proof-writing

$F$ is the cumulative distribution function, having the property of right continuity

The question here is exactly, proving that for the increasing function F it suffices to restrain the study on the sequence $x_n = x_0 + \frac{1}{n}$ to prove the right continuity of $F$ , so this is not a question for the proof , this question followed the proof which used $x_n = x_0 + \frac{1}{n}$

copied quick hints , on one way we can do it (may contain errors) :

> for a given h>0 , we note $A_n=]a, a+h/n]$
> use the theorem of the continuity
> applied on the decreasing set
>
> retraining to $x_n = x_0 + \frac{1}{n}$ is not sufficient in the general case we need to
> prove it for any increasing sequence (a counter example is the limit of the
> indicator function of rationals at $0$)
>
> We have $An= \cup_{ j= n}^{\infty} A_j \setminus A_{j+1} $ and so:
> $P(A_n)=\sum_{j=n}^{+\infty}P(A_j \setminus A_{j+1} ) $
>
> $P(A_j \setminus A_{j+1} )$ is then the general term of a converging
> series: $P(A_1)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}P(A_j \setminus A_{j+1})$
>
> the remainder of this serie is $P(A_n)$ which tends to zero , but
> $P(A_n)=F(a+h/n)-F(a)$

I don't really understand this, or the pertinence of the use of the indicator function of rationals, I know in general it doesn't suffice to restrain to the sequence $x_n = x_0 + \frac{1}{n}$ and we need to prove it for any increasing sequence, so my question is how to prove it is sufficient to do that in this case?

Comment: Thank you,that's right, I'll correct it

Comment: Now what is $h$ in $F(a+h/n)$?

Comment: Oh yeah thank you, I'll correct that too, it's , for a given $h>0$ , we note $A_n=]a, a+h/n]$

Comment: $F$ is non-decreasing, so a standard theorem of analysis guarantees that $F$ has one-sided limits (left and right) at every point. To prove right continuity it suffices to study $F(x+u_n)$ for any sequence $u_n$ that is non-negative and non-increasing. $u_n=\frac 1n$ is such a sequence.

Comment: @Gabriel Romon would you please remind me of the standard theorem? I may need to use the arguments of the standard theorem in this case in Lebesgue measure context

Comment: @Khan see e.g. [Theorem 5.60 here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Wlb-o7HBh2YC&ppis=_e&lpg=PA228&ots=P3zzKgfYOG&dq=nondecreasing%20function%20one%20sided%20limits&pg=PA228#v=onepage&q=nondecreasing%20function%20one%20sided%20limits&f=false)

Comment: interval $I$ in this theorem is supposed to be a closed bounded interval of R , I might need to verify it is the case on the probability space for the cdf ..

Answer (score 1):

The following may help:

Proposition 1: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an increasing
function. Let $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the following are equivalent:

(a) $f$ is right-continuous at $x_{0}$,

(b) Define $x_{n}=x_{0}+\frac{1}{n}$, then $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x_{0})$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

/////////////////////////////

Clearly $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$.

We go to show that $(b)\Rightarrow(a)$.

Let $A=\{f(x)\mid x\in(x_{0},\infty)\}$ and $f(x_{0}+):=\inf A$.
For each $x>x_{0}$, we have $f(x)\geq f(x_{0})$. Therefore, the
set $A$ is bounded from below by $f(x_{0})$. Hence, $f(x_{0}+)\geq f(x_{0})$.
We prove that $f(x_{0}+)=f(x_{0})$ by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that
$f(x_{0}+)>f(x_{0})$. Choose $c$ such that $f(x_{0}+)>c>f(x_{0})$.
Observe that $f(x_{n})\in A$, so $f(x_{n})\geq\inf A>c$. Letting
$n\rightarrow\infty$, we have $f(x_{0})\geq c$, which is a contradiction.

Now it is trivial to show that $f$ is right-continuous at $x_{0}$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Note that $f(x_{0}+)+\varepsilon$
is not a lower bound of $A$, so there exists $x_{1}\in(x_{0},\infty)$
such that $f(x_{1})<f(x_{0}+)+\varepsilon$. Define $\delta=x_{1}-x_{0}>0$.
For any $x\in(x_{0},x_{1})$, we have $f(x_{0})\leq f(x)\leq f(x_{1})<f(x_{0}+)+\varepsilon=f(x_{0})+\varepsilon$.
That is, $|f(x)-f(x_{0})|<\varepsilon$ whenever $x\in[x_{0},x_{0}+\delta)$.
Hence, $f$ is right-continuous at $x_{0}$.

Comment: Thank you, I think this proves that 

$f(x_0 +1/n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ $\iff$ $f$ is right continuous at $x_0$ in case we accept that it is possible to restrain the definition of increasing function to $x_0 + 1/n$

but my question is about proving the sufficiency of restraining the study on $x_n = x_0 + 1/n$ while we need to prove it for any increasing sequence

Comment: As long as your function is increasing, it is OK to just consider sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n = x_0 + \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: If $f$ is not increasing, of course it does not work by just considering a single sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument. For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $F(x)-F(x_0)<\epsilon$ whenever $x\in(x_0,x_0+\delta)$ (so that $F$ is right-continuous at $x_0$). To see this note that there exists $N$ s.t. $F(x_0+1/n)-F(x_0)<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ ($\because F(x_0+1/n)\to F(x_0)$). Since $F$ is non-decreasing, the same is true for any $x\in (x_0,x_0+1/N)$.

Comment: My reasoning might be incorrect , I need to write this properly, but I think  it is some version of this , using the sequence of F , and more based on the measure of the possible singletons where it is not the case having the null measure , so it includes a wider range of functions than just the functions that verify this in the epsilon delta definition? The probability function is a measure, the measure of $A_n$ is null because it's an intersection of sets converging to ]a,a] and P(]a,a])=0 , given the hints this is the result I think it wants but I don't see what I am missing about the suffi

Comment: The sequential definition of right-continuity is equivalent to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition and for the latter it suffices to check that $F(x_0+1/n)\to F(x_0)$ (by monotonicity of $F$).